# Hibernate 6 Left Join Newest member of collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

In Hibernate 6.2 I would like to get a `Author` entity with the newest `Book` if there is a matching book, and into a Dto projection - `AuthorBookDto` :

**Author**

```
public class Author {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "author_seq")
private Long id;

@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "author")
private List<Book> listBook = new ArrayList<>();

// other fields
// getters and setters
```

**Book**

```
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "book_seq")
private Long id;

@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
private Author author;    

private LocalDateTime publishedDateTime;
```

And the Dto that I want to project into contains some fields from `Author` and the newest `Book` from the Book collection:

**AuthorBookDto**

```
public class AuthorBookDto {

// Selected fields from Author plus a book entity (the newest one)
public Long authorId;
public Long bookId;
public Book newestBook;
```

I wrote a query which got as far as selecting a `Author` and can retrieve indvidual fields from `Book` but not a whole book entity (the query below does not project correctly to the above entity):

```
    public Test customQuery3(Long id) {
    return (Test) entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT NEW com.view.Test(a.id, a.name, y.pub_max_date) FROM Author a " +
                            "LEFT JOIN(SELECT book.id as book_id, MAX(book.pubDateTime) as pub_max_date, book.author.id as bid FROM Book b WHERE book.author.id=:id) as y " +
                            "ON a.id=y.bid " +
                            "WHERE a.id=:id GROUP BY a.id, y.book_id ORDER BY y.pub_max_date DESC LIMIT 1")
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
```

The result should look like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Steven King",
        Book {"id": "1",
              "title":"The Shining",
              "publishedDateTime":"2023-01-01 13:00"
              }
 }
```

Is this possible in one HQL query?
(Note: Some authors may not have published any books)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query works:

```
@Override
public Test customQuery3(Long id) {
    return (Test) entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT NEW com.view.Test(a.id, b) FROM Author a " +
                            "LEFT JOIN Book b ON b.author.id=a.id " +
                            "WHERE b.id=:id " +
                            "GROUP BY a, b ORDER BY b.newestBook DESC LIMIT 1")
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

The ordering on `b.newestBook` puts the newest at the top and the `.getSingleResult()` and `LIMIT 1` both ensure that only 1 result is returned.