# Single Item from Entity Collection into Nested Dto

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, dto, mapstruct

I have a entity Author that has a collection of Books with property publishedDate.

Each Author has a collection books and they are mapped like so:

```
public class Author {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> listBook = new ArrayList<>();

    // other fields
    // getters and setters
```

Book

```
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Author author;    

    private LocalDateTime publishedDateTime;
```

I would like to get a Author By Id with the newest Book as a Dto, i.e.

```
@Data
public AuthorNewestBookDto {

    Long authorId;
    String name;
   
    Book newestBook;
```

1. DtoProjection

Cast the results of the query directly into the Dto. No mapper required. Efficient transaction on
database. Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005546/hibernate-6-left-join-newest-member-of-collection).

2. Mapper

Use a mapstruct mapper to return an Author entity with a collection of books and use the @Before
annotation to return only the single newest book from the collection. Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74208260/mapstruct-how-to-conditionally-drop-members-of-a-collection).

Is there a better way to do this conversion to AuthorNewestBookDto where I need to retrieve the single newest member of a collection into a nested singular Dto.

I have considered if I could do it in hibernate stage with a DtoResultTransformer (Hibernate 6).

Hopefully this is not too opinionated for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapStruct has multiple tools for situations like this:

#### 1. `Qualifier`

We can provide custom mapping logic between Entity field type: `List<Book>` and DTO field type `Book`:

```
interface BookingMapping {
    @Mapping(target = "newestBook", source = "listBook", qualifiedBy=NewestBookQualifier.class)
    //.. other fields
    AuthorNewestBookDto toDtoQualifiedBy(Author entity);
}
...
public class BookingMappingUtil { 
    @NewestBookQualifier
    BookDto toNewestBook(List<Book> listBook) {
        return listBook.stream()
             .max(Comparator.comparing(Book::getPublishedDateTime))
             .orElse(null)
}
...
@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface NewestBookQualifier{
}
```

[Iterable to non-iterable example](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/main/mapstruct-iterable-to-non-iterable/src/main/java/com/mycompany/mapper/SourceTargetMapper.java) (official MapStruct-Example project).

#### 2. `@Named`

In this case, we don't need to create a new annotation. [Named-annotation documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers)

```
@Mapping(target = "newestBook", source = "listBook", qualifiedByName="toNewestBook" )
//.. other fields
AuthorNewestBookDto toDtoQualifiedByName(Author entity);

@Named("toNewestBook")
default BookDto toNewestBook(List<Book> listBook) {
    return listBook.stream()
             .max(Comparator.comparing(Book::getPublishedDateTime))
             .orElse(null)
}
```

#### 3. `@Mapping(.. expression=".." ..)`

We are able to store business logic as a String. This approach can be not readable but very easy to implement. [expressions documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions)

```
@Mapping(target = "newestBook", 
          source = "listBook", 
          expression = "java( listBook.stream().max(java.util.Comparator.comparing(Book::getPublishedDateTime)).orElse(null) )" )
//.. other fields
AuthorNewestBookDto toDtoQualifiedByName(Author entity);
```